# Issue with constructor in java

Tags: java

I've started learning java just recently so forgive me if it's stupid problem, I have 3 classes in 3 files. 
First one

```
package PLAYLIST1;

public class Utwor {
    private String tytul1;
    private String wykonawca2;
    private Integer rok3;

    Utwor(String x, String y, Integer z){
        x=tytul1;
        y=wykonawca2;
        z=rok3;
    }
    public String tytul(){
        return tytul1;      
    }
    public String wykonawca(){
        return wykonawca2;
    }
    public Integer rok(){
        return rok3;
    }
    public void piosenka(){
         System.out.println(tytul1+" ("+wykonawca2+") ["+rok3+"]");
    }

}
```

Second

```
package PLAYLIST1;

import java.util.Arrays;

 class Playlist {
    //ArrayList<String> listaUtworow;
    Utwor[] listaU = new Utwor[3];
    private String lista;
    private int ileJuzJest = 0;



    Playlist(String nazwaListy) {
        //listaUtworow = new ArrayList<String>();
        lista = nazwaListy;
    }

    public String Nazwa() {
        return lista;
    }

    public void dodajUtwor(String tytul, String album, Integer rok) {
        listaU[ileJuzJest] = new Utwor(tytul,album ,rok);
        ileJuzJest++;
        System.out.println("Dodano utwór: '"+tytul+"' do listy: "+lista);
    }



    public void wyswietlListe() {
        if (ileJuzJest==0) {
            System.out.println("Lista jest pusta");
        }
        System.out.println("Utwory z listy "+lista+":");
        for (int i=0; i<ileJuzJest; i++) {
             listaU[i].piosenka();
        }
    }
}
```

And final with main

```
package PLAYLIST1;

public class ZarzadzaniePlaylistami {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Playlist p1 = new Playlist("Rock");
        Playlist p2 = new Playlist("Pop");

        System.out.println(p1.Nazwa());
        System.out.println(p2.Nazwa());
        p1.dodajUtwor("Stockholm Syndrome","Absolution",2004);
        p1.dodajUtwor("Absolution","Going to Hell",2014);
        p1.dodajUtwor("Loud Like Love","Loud Like Love",2013);
        p2.dodajUtwor("Blank Space","A",2014);
        p2.dodajUtwor("Sugar","B",2013);
        p2.dodajUtwor("Budapest","C",2012);
        p1.wyswietlListe();
        p2.wyswietlListe();




    }

}
```

As I run program the result is:

```
Rock
Pop
Dodano utwór: 'Stockholm Syndrome' do listy: Rock
Dodano utwór: 'Absolution' do listy: Rock
Dodano utwór: 'Loud Like Love' do listy: Rock
Dodano utwór: 'Blank Space' do listy: Pop
Dodano utwór: 'Sugar' do listy: Pop
Dodano utwór: 'Budapest' do listy: Pop
Utwory z listy Rock:
null (null) [null]
null (null) [null]
null (null) [null]
Utwory z listy Pop:
null (null) [null]
null (null) [null]
null (null) [null]
```

Why those variables doesn't save in Utwor class? I've been struggling with this for hour and I'm not going to solve it on my own, please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backwards assignments in your Utwor constructor as you're assigning the fields (null) the parameter variables:

```
Utwor(String x, String y, Integer z){
    x=tytul1;
    y=wykonawca2;
    z=rok3;
}
```

instead, you should assign the parameters to the fields, and so it should be:

```
Utwor(String x, String y, Integer z){
    tytul1 = x;
    wykonawca2 = y;
    rok3 = z;
}
```

Interestingly, you get it right in your Playlist class.

Nicely asked question, by the way.